# Can't loop through Ember.Deffered Object in the template

Tags: ember.js

I want to show issues that I get from Ember.Deferred resolve.
and pass it to the controller. But it shows error.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="magazines/show/issues">
{{#if issues}}

    {{#each issue in issues}}
      <li class="has-sub">
        <a href="#">{{issue.name}}</a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
            <li {{action showGenericData issue}}><a href="#">Generic</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inside</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    {{/each}}

{{else}}

    <li>No Issue</li>

{{/if}}
```

Code for the model

```
var dfd = Ember.Deferred.create();
        var issues = Em.A();

        $.getJSON( App._api_path +  "issues/" + mag_id , 
        function(response){

            response.forEach(function(m){
                issues.pushObject(App.Issue.create(m));
            });

            dfd.resolve(issues);
        });

        return dfd;
```

Error in the console

```
Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed <Ember.Deferred:ember285> ember-1.3.1.js:3285

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver'
```

Please, help. Thanks...

Comment: where are you returning this property from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were returning this from the model hook it would work fine.  If you are returning it from some computed property you should just return issues.

```
 var dfd = Ember.Deferred.create();
 var issues = Em.A();

 $.getJSON( App._api_path +  "issues/" + mag_id , 
   function(response){

    response.forEach(function(m){
       issues.pushObject(App.Issue.create(m));
        });

    dfd.resolve(issues);
});

return issues;
```